# UserManager with Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Do you still use user manager when explicitly using Azure Active Directory for authentication?

Comment: Can you  explain more about your concern and about Azure ad manager please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadusermanager?view=azureadps-2.0#example-1--get-the-manager-of-a-user)

Comment: Well UserManager has functionality like register or delete user, which is no longer managed by me if you using AAD only.  I understand I don’t have to expose all features, but I’m curious how others use Identity when using AAD as the only auth

Comment: Yes, user are managed in Azure ad by [User management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/#:~:text=Azure%20AD%20user%20management%20services%20such%20as%20groups,or%20delegate%20permissions%20to%20distribute%20identity%20management%20tasks.).In order to authenticate the users in user manager explicit we need AAD authentication